# Get substring including the brackets C#

Tags: c#, substring

- I have an excel file where I get 2 strings, one without brackets and one with brackets. While i can fetch the data if I am aware of the start and end word like in the below first string example are 'string' and 'fetch' respectively.
- The second string comes with bracket anywhere in between the letters hence i cannot predict the index of the brackets. When I give the startWord as 'string' and endword as 'fetch' I want the code to work by including the bracket and get everything in between just like the firstString example.
- The below is the code I am using which is perfectly running for firstString. Need help in secondString output.

  ```
       string startWord = "string";
       string endWord = "fetch";
       string firstString = "the string i want to fetch is this";
       string secondString = "the strin{9.6}g i want{6.2} to fet{5.2}ch is this";

       int pFrom = firstString.ToLower().IndexOf(startWord) + startWord.Length;
       int pTo = firstString.ToLower().IndexOf(endWord, pFrom);

       string firstStringOutput = firstString.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom).Trim(); // current output I am getting i want to
       //string secondStringExpextedOutput = "i want{6.2} to"; // the output I want including the brackets for secondString
  ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's give Regex a chance.

```
var pattern1 = string.Concat(startWord.Select(x => x + @"({\d\.\d})*"));
var pattern2 = string.Concat(endWord.Select(x => x + @"({\d\.\d})*"));

var m1 = Regex.Match(secondString, pattern1);
var m2 = Regex.Match(secondString, pattern2);

int from = m1.Index + m1.Length;
int to = m2.Index;

string secondStringOutput = secondString[from..to].Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string startWord = "{";
        string endWord = "}";
        string firstString = "This is my first string which I want to read";
        string secondString = "This is m{0.5}y first str{2.3}ing which I wa{5.6}nt to read";
        var foundIndexes = new SortedDictionary<int, string[] >();
        for (int i = secondString.IndexOf(startWord); i > -1; i = secondString.IndexOf(startWord, i + 1))
        {
            int pTo = secondString.ToLower().IndexOf(endWord, i);
            foundIndexes.Add(i, new string[] { pTo.ToString(), secondString.Substring(i, pTo - i + 1).Trim() });
        }

        startWord = "my";
        endWord = "want";
        int pFrom = firstString.ToLower().IndexOf(startWord) + startWord.Length;
        int pToIndex = firstString.ToLower().IndexOf(endWord, pFrom);
        firstString = firstString.Substring(pFrom, pToIndex - pFrom).Trim();
        string output = firstString;
        foreach (int startIndex in foundIndexes.Keys)
        {
            if (startIndex > pFrom)
            {
                int length = output.Length;
                if (startIndex - pFrom < length)
                {
                    output = output.Insert(startIndex - pFrom, foundIndexes[startIndex][1]);
                }
            }
            
        }
```

The above code works where the end word also contains a {percentage}. The output we get is 'first string wh{2.3}ich I' which is exactly what I was expecting. Hope it helps someone who might have a similar use case.